# Can I use Android App Bundles to reduce creating multiple APKs?

Tags: android

I have looked at the documentation about the App Bundles [Android App Bundles Develop Document](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle). I have am curious, for suppose I am providing my application for different screen size mobiles(like small, medium etc.) In order to support this, if I am building different APKs for each, can the concept of "About Android App Bundles" help me reduce this redundancy size or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You will not have to build different apks for different screen sizes
You can use layout resource modifiers and that is very well covered in the Android Documentation under [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

The question of building different or "Split APKs" would come when your app is really big and not all of the functionality of that app would be required. You can create different gradle modules and produce independent apk in that case

When you use an Android Bundle, it is like a big fat apk which will be built on demand according to the different architectures which the mobile devices use for example x86, x64, arm7 etc

You can supply an Android App Bundle to the Play Store portal while deploying your app and Play Store will automatically install the best possible version for the device on which it is to be installed